# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-7, m2eclipse

I'm compiling a project in Eclipse using m2eclipse. I set the JDK path in Eclipse like this:

```
Windows-->preferences-->installed jres--> jdk1.7.xx  path
```

But this is showing an error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE    rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.424s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 29 15:21:01 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-   plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TEST-WEB: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Comment: how are you starting the compile? Commandline? Eclipse tool?

Comment: from eclipse tool Run configuration--> Goals: clean install

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Package Compilation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220392/maven-package-compilation-error)

Comment: Hey, This error is coming because Maven is trying to get JDK but in eclipse it is pointing to JRE. You can change path to JDK and it will work. Check below post which will help you http://learn-automation.com/maven-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-selenium/

Comment: i'm posting link this so that someone in future may get benefited as i did. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33873838/4525120

Comment: Advanced users for whom this is a frequent problem, may include the standalone eclipse compiler in their pom, instead of relying on javac.

Comment: I have this issue every time I run as mvn install in eclipse. the workaround I have found is to clean the project one time that changes the environment back to JDK than run as mvn install. Works For me every time.

Answer (score 1087, accepted):

1. On your Eclipse IDE, go into ***Window*** > ***Preferences*** > ***Java*** > ***Installed JREs*** > and check your ***installed JREs***. You should have an entry with a JDK there.
2. Select the Execution Env as show below. Click ***OK***
3. Then ***Right-Click*** on your Project  -> ***Maven*** -> ***Update Project***

Additionally, you may have to change Maven JRE (see @jlars62 answer) which is as follows. Goto Run -> Run Configurations, selecting the Maven Build I was running (from the left panel). Then, I clicked the JRE tab and selected the option Workspace default JRE

[image]

Comment: @jaipster I tried to do this, but I could not find the jdk in the left panel, I only can see the jre7. Do you know why?

Comment: It could possibly be either you have jdk7 not installed on your machine or it is not configured in eclipse. Can you confirm.

Comment: I have same issue as @Diode. I do have both JDK and JRE installed in my machine. And path looks like JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25. What do you mean by "not configured in eclipse"?

Comment: @Diode I had the same problem. I went to "Installed JREs" and clicked "Add..." From there I browsed to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_XX and then I could select the jre as jaipster described.

Comment: For me it was enough just to add the JDK to the list of "Installed JREs" (not the best naming...) and checking the check box beside the new JDK entry making it the default VM.

Comment: Looks like updating my Java made it switch to the new JRE, not caring at all that there was no JDK attached to it. Stupid Eclipse...

Comment: I clicked the "Search" button in the "Installed JREs" menu. Eclipse searched  one the drives I pointed it to and came out with all the installed JREs and JDKs.

Comment: I refactored/renamed my project and immediately had this problem.
This fix resolved it.  

- I'm running Eclipse IDE: Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: For step 1 I chose my JDK instead of the JRE and set it as default. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Update project was not enough for me. I had to clean.

Comment: Check if JAVA_HOME is also set to avoid such issue

Comment: Just don't confuse between jre and jdk. You have to add jdk installation path not jre

Comment: For me, I verified these settings were correct as suggested, and cleaned the project, but it still failed.  Finally I closed and reopened Eclipse and then it succeeded.  So, there was something stuck about Eclipse that wasn't fixed until I restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 153):

1. Set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the JDK root folder -  required if you run command line or maven (`mvn`).

   - (Search google for `JAVA_HOME` for more info)
2. In project properties in section Java Compiler select required JDK - if you run directly from eclipse

Comment: Why is step 1 required?

Comment: @DuncanJones, first is required if you run command line or maven(google for this variable), second - if you run directly from eclipse,

Comment: I would add that information to your answer. Otherwise it suggests both are necessary in all cases.

Comment: Pay attention that the JAVA_HOME does *not* end with "bin", but points to the *root* of the JDK.

Comment: Needed this for the release-plugin as it doesn't use the jre settings from eclipse (with external maven installation)...

Comment: This is a much better approach than changing the build path/run configuration settings in Eclipse for developers who are not using the IDE but using the command line tool of maven

Comment: This did the trick :)
I forgot to define the `JAVA_HOME` variable when setting up the `mvn` command line application

Comment: Yeap thats what I just did, cause I'm using visual studio code, so using terminal
Thanks

Comment: While setting `JAVA_HOME` use `Progra~1` instead of `Program files` since it has space in between e.g. `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_251`

Answer (score 149):

For me, it is exactly what the maven of eclipse complains

[image]

So, I press `Edit` button and change path to the JDK Folder, then clean project and everything starts to work

Comment: I'd rather suggest to add the JRE using the "Add" button then manipulating a JRE entry to become a JDK entry! And after adding the JDK click the checkbox beside the JDK entry. This should already solve the issue(s) described in this post.

Comment: It is weird . because as the title of dialog shows this should place the `Installed JREs` instead of jdk folder. But It really solved me problem.  Thanks

Comment: It's weired the title is Installed JREs but path is JDK but anyway it works thanks

Comment: It's a good idea to remove the JRE after adding the JDK. Sometimes Eclipse keeps using the JRE regardless - no idea why this is the case. Making the JDK the only available option helps. :)

Answer (score 143):

For me, nothing worked until I made this change to my pom.xml:

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Other Notes*

I could see that m2e was executing in a JRE, not the JDK.  Nothing I did changed this, including adding this to the eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

In the end I never got m2e to execute in a JDK, but setting the Java compiler explicitly (as above) did the trick.

Comment: This solution should be implemented as a last resort, since the project itself is modified to be coupled to your current dev machine.

Comment: @ksnortum thanks! this is the only thing that made it work for me.

Comment: What about us linux folks here?

Comment: I suspect it's pretty much the same, except the executable would be /path/to/java/bin/javac.  Maybe try 'which java` to find your Java path.

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Thanks

Answer (score 48):

**In my case it was solved by doing this:**

Go to your 'Runtime Configuration' and configure your JRE to an JDK.

[image: Select the right JDK for your Runtime]

[image: Select default JRE]

I copied answer just in case it is deleted for some reason, but the source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617639/1754020)

Comment: This worked for me. If JDK is not displayed in Alternate JRE dropdown, so you need to Add Installed JRE(Navigate to the folder where JDK is installed) and select the JDK folder.

Comment: This was my problem, thanks for your answer it got solved.

Answer (score 41):

I was getting this error when trying to do a maven build from within eclipse.

For me, the answer was going to `Run` -> `Run Configurations`, selecting the `Maven Build` I was running (from the left panel). Then, I clicked the `JRE` tab and selected the option `Workspace default JRE`

Comment: This appears to be necessary to check in addition to the selected answer above.

Comment: I like this solution better, as it does not make you change the default java version for other projects.

Answer (score 37):

> Go to windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

may be jre is already added
[image]

> click on Add -> Standard VM -> Next -> Directory

and browse for the JDK
in my case path was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`

> then Click on finish.

you will see window like this[image]

> select JDK -> Apply -> Ok

And You are done.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the JDK path. 
It seemed as though people could choose another option to click JDK when I only had JRE displayed from the beginning. I added JDK from the path you had provided.

Answer (score 23):

I got same issue and i just add `JAVA_HOME` to **environment variables**.

[image: env var]

- If you are using eclipse, just refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279068/6097074
- If you are using intellij, just after adding `JAVA_HOME` open command prompt from project directory and run `mvn clean install`(don't use intellij terminal).

Comment: I would like to highlight that my `JAVA_HOME` path was already pointing to the `bin` folder and after trying both subfolders for either JRE and JDK I figured the path in your example actually is not the `bin` folder, which felt a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: worked for me. i didn't have JAVA_HOME in environment variables, i think you should add it in both, and also don't use intellij terminal

Answer (score 14):

I tried all of the above, however, still getting the same error message.

In my case an actual JRE was incorrectly used as JRE System Library in the project-specific build path which was obviously overriding all those other settings discussed here.

If that is so in your case try the following:

1. Open the project-specific libraries of the Java Build Path: Right-click "Project > Build Path > Configure Build Path..." and select "Libraries" tab.
2. Select the "JRE System Library" entry and hit "Remove".
3. Hit "Add Library...".
4. A wizard pops up. Select "JRE System Library" and hit "Next >".
5. Now select the correct JDK (in my case "Workspace default JRE", which I
   configured using a JDK).
6. Close wizard by hitting "Finish".
7. Close "Properties" dialog by hitting "OK".

Comment: I have tried all above option mentioned by @ishu, but still getting org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hibernateTest1: Compilation failure, then I tried your solution , but no change in error... Please help me.

Comment: Add `<build>
  <sourceDirectory>flockWebclient</sourceDirectory>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>resources</directory>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>` in your pom.xml

Answer (score 12):

An alternative if jaipster's answer does not work is to go to:
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

Then to edit the jre so that it points to the jdk and not the jre (the jre home filed in the jre package editor)

That worked for me.

Comment: That was it for me. Funny is that sometimes I get errors that the default JRE is erroneously pointing to a JDK.

Comment: worked for me, I want to do maven clean install compile

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue while trying to build a jar file of my project application using `mvn clean install`, though the application was working fine while running from Eclipse.

The issue was, indeed too naive, that I had not set the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable. All I had to do is set JAVA_HOME environment variable to JDK directory, make sure it is not till **"\bin"** and without **semi-colon ";"**.

[image]

How I understood it is as:

The application worked fine in Eclipse as *JRE System Library* was referring to JRE *inside* the JDK folder instead of external JRE folder without JDK. [As explained very well in other answers]

This configuration does not apply to *maven* command that we run on command prompt. It will still look for JAVA_HOME variable to access the JRE System library and when it is not found it refers to external JRE folder without JDK.

Comment: The important things for those who run from mvn command, is need to set JAVA_HOME and point to JDK directory. Thanks for this

Answer (score 11):

If you are running the `Maven` command from `cmd`, make sure you set the jdk path before running the command. In my case, I have created a `.bat` file containing the following:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
start cmd.exe /k "cd c:\aem_proj\sis\aau"
```

Answer (score 11):

My answer pertains to the Eclipse in Windows environment.

I went to Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs
I did NOT see the JDK in here. I only saw the JRE here.
So I added the JDK and then unchecked the JRE. Then checked JDK.
Then I ran the POM file using Run Configurations. Choose the tab JRE and select the option "Workspace Default..."
Here are the images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are several options to specify.

Steps:
Right on project in project explorer
Go to Run-> Run Configuration -> Click Maven Build -> Click on your build config/or create a new config. 
You will see the window as the given snapshot below, click on JRE tab there.

You see you have 3 options 1) Workspace Default JRE 2)Execution Environment 3)Alternate JRE
[image]
1) Workspace Default JRE is set from 'Window' menu on the top -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -Here you can add your jdk
[image]
2) Execution Environment jdk can be set in pom.xml as mentioned by @ksnortum

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

3) Alternate JRE can be used to select a jdk from your directory

Answer (score 7):

**Problem statement** = No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? intellij

**Solution**

Please set the **Environment variabl**e like below to solve the issue

**Variable name** : JAVA_HOME

**Variable Value** : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

**Variable name** : M2_HOME

**Variable Value** : C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0

**Moreover**, Add Java and maven path in "**System Variables**" like below:

1. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
2. C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin

Answer (score 7):

Though the question is about the error with `Eclipse` setup but thought an answer of fixing this error with `IntelliJ` and Windows 10 setup may also be helpful here.

**1**. Go to `File` --> `Settings` --> `Build, Execution, Deployment` --> `Build Tools` --> `Maven` --> `Importing`

**2**. Set `JDK` for `Importer` as shown below to `JAVA_HOME`

[image]

Also `JAVA_HOME` should be set to `JDK` path at Environment Variables --> System variables and also add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to Path System variables

Answer (score 5):

For me the JRE was in the PATH environment variable before the JDK path

1. C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
2. C:\env\jdk1.8.0_151\bin

So I removed 1. Probably swapping them would fix it too.

Answer (score 3):

There is another possible answer to this question, and I may be the only person foolish enough to have stumbled upon this, but I think it's worth adding, since none of the other answers applied as I already had those settings correct.

When you install a JDK, the installer asks you where you want to install the files. By default, on Windows, this is something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74 (or whatever version you are installing).

It then asks you for a directory to install the JRE to, which by default is something like C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74.

Note that one is **jdk**1.8.0_74 and the other is **jre**1.8.0_74

I was rushing things, and thinking the installer was asking me the same question twice, set both my JDK and JRE install locations to D:\devtools\jdk\jdk1.8.0_74, resulting in the installer overwriting the JDK with the JRE. This resulted in (among other things) a missing javac.exe in my JDK bin, and the same error the OP reported here in all my maven builds.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution.

The most common solution for this problem is to change ***jdk location*** as my ***Installed JREs*** instead of the ***JRE location*** but that did not solve my problem this one time.

So I did the below to solve the problem.
Expand the **Installed JREs** tab and you will find a ***Execution environments*** tab.

Click on your favourite execution environment. In my case it was ***JAVASE-1.8***. There it shows 2 options. ***JDK and JRE***. Select ***JDK*** there and the problem is solved.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried most of the answers without success. 
What worked for me was (after following https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279068/2408893):

- right click on project -> Properties
- select Java Build Path
- select the JRE System Library
- click edit
  [image]
- In execution environment select a jdk

[image]

- click Finish
- build and run

Answer (score 2):

I did the following change and it worked for me.Hope it helps someone.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just wasted 3 hours with this problem until I managed to make it work.
I had this error in the Eclipse Terminal when issuing a mvn compile command:

**No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?**

So I read here that I have to make a new system variable called JAVA_HOME and make it point towards the jdk installation folder. However this generated another error:

**Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later**

Couldn't find a fix for this one so...

**So the fix to make it all go away is install Java SE Development Kit 8!** 
I was using 9 thinking that if it's the latest it must be better...

Anyway...

1. Uninstall all java versions from your computer
2. Install JDK8 from here:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. Then define the JAVA_HOME system environmental value - tutorial here:
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3208/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/
4. Restart Eclipse and enjoy! (at least that's what I did)

Hoping this spares some poor wanderer of some trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had system variable path has "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" location.

In "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" location java, javaw only there. So I am getting the same error.

Once I removed all files in "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" folder my error got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable> path to jdk \bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue, the mistake i made was i added jre path only in the path var,not jdk path .When jdk path was added to path and build the maven project its working perfect .Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Add new JRE definition (select path JDK), worked for me.

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I created a new EC2 ubuntu 16.04 instance with Java already installed on it and while running mvn clean package, I encountered this issue and the below solution worked for me.

If you are working on an Ubuntu server, then you can try installing Java again and for that you can use this answer [How to install the JDK on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-the-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 - 64 bit, there is a permissions problem which prevents the installer from unpacking the file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.xx\lib\tools.jar into your local. This jar file is what maven-compiler-plugin version 3.x uses instead of the usual javac

**Solution:** Run, as an administrator, the Java JDK installer! And make sure the tools.jar is sitting in the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.xx\lib\

In case you are using m2e maven integration plugin, you want to see the file is visible to Eclipse via the following steps inside Eclipse:

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
Select the JDK you are using (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.xx)
Press Edit to see the list of jars including tools.jar, OR you can add it as Add External JAR
Then configure the maven run through these steps:

Run->Run configurations->Fill in Name, Base directory and Goals.
Then in the same window move to the JRE tab and point to the JDK \jdk1.6.xx\

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, doing a docker example, I must not have had the JDK installed just the JRE. After `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` and setting JAVA_HOME in profile and adding JAVA_HOME/bin to the path, it built!

Comment: this is the one that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had upgraded to Big Sur Mac OS and I had to remove this and then it worked fine.

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer above, I could say that just try to run Maven from the terminal (outside of Eclipse). In this way, if it builds from outside but not in Eclipse, you can understand that the problem should be in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers regarding this question but all are related to right path configuration of JDK, but with JRE only we can solve this problem.

We just need to make use of deployment assembly to configure the path of packaged war file of the Java EE Project and then re-run the maven-install.

Steps to make use of deployment assembly:

1. Right click on the Jave EE project --> click on Properties
       --> click on Deployment Assembly
2. Click on Add button --> Click on Archives from the File
       System --> Click on next --> Click on Add --> Go to the
       .m2\respository directory and search for the war file generated -->
       Select war file --> Click on Open button --> Click on Apply --> OK
3. Right click on the project --> Click on Maven Install under
       Run As

This will build your project successfully, without any compiler error.

Hope this solves the problem without JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing any maven build.

Apart from above JRE changes.I still faced similar issue.I was missing JUnit dependency after adding it is working fine.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs I did NOT see the JDK in here. I only saw the JRE here. So I added the JDK.

here we have to mandatory remove JRE instead of just unchecking.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project and run as maven install then again run your application.
if this didnt work go to the folder of your project directly start command line and run 'mvn install'[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is looking for JDK and is founding JRE.

Recommended Solution: 
**Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit > Click on directory > Browse JDK path....**

That should work fine.
 It worked fine for me!!

Answer (score 0):

While building the project, make sure to point the jre to jdk path. This can be done in Run configuration section for the particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Please for windows uses

1. If you are using intellij, just after adding JAVA_HOME open command prompt from project directory and run mvn clean install(don't use intellij terminal).
2. set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202