# Error found when trying to compile code

Tags: java, maven

When I try to maven run the test code, this error pops up:

```
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 21 17:17:47 CST 2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/61M 
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project java-checks: Compilation failure 
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I run Maven from Eclipse and have set a JDK in `Preference > Java > Installed JREs` but I still get that error.

What are the solutions to it?

Comment: A little more context would help. How are you running Maven? How did you "configure the JDK"?

Comment: Through the preference > java > installed jres > chek on idk file

Comment: Are you running this through an IDE, or through the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Comment: Searching for `Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?` on SO gives a solution to your problem. Please stop wasting people's time by asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set your `JAVA_HOME` variable correctly, or `$JAVA_HOME/bin` (`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`) is not on your `PATH` variable (I would advise you put this at the beginning of the `PATH` environment variable).

Comment: I've set the environment variables for java_home and path.

Comment: What are they set to? Please, mention this in your question. Also, what do you get when you execute `mvn --version`?

Comment: C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\sonar-java\java-checks>mvn -version

C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\sonar-java\java-checks>set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024
m
Maven version: 2.0.9
Java version: 1.7.0_51
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"

Comment: Java Home:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
Path:C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\apache-maven-2.0.9\bin

Comment: Do you have you JAVA_HOME in the path?

Comment: You need to have `JAVA_HOME/bin` on your `PATH`.

Comment: And don't put these as answers to the comments, add them as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to set a JDK in "installed JREs" when you run Maven from Eclipse. Eclipse itself also has to run in a JDK.

To make sure of that, edit the `eclipse.ini` in your Eclipse folder. Add somtehing like

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javaw.exe
```

of course with the right path to your JDK.