# Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Getting this error while building the sprint boot application through eclipse.

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

but working fine if i build through command prompt.
 Attaching the pom.xml below.

### Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sarun</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringAngular</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name> SpringDataRestAngular</name>
    <description>Spring + AngularJS </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.programmingfree.springservice.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How exactly do you start the build in Eclipse? Do you use any kind of wizard to run maven? If so, just put in the goals, not the mvn command itself.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you are using debug configuration for maven, use the  command

```
clean install
```

And skip all the tests.

Answer (score 23):

Try without command `mvn` in the command line. Example:

From:

```
mvn clean install jetty:run
```

To:

```
clean install jetty:run
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the reply. 
I was using "mvn clean install" in the maven build configuration.
we no need to use "mvn" command if running through eclipse.

After buiding the application using the command "clean install" , I got one more error -
"No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

I followed this link:-
[No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

now application building is fine in eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error. I was using Intellij IDEA and I wanted to run Spring boot application. So, solution from my side is as follow.

Go to Run menu -> Run configuration -> Click on Add button from the left panel and select maven -> In parameters add this text -> `spring-boot:run`

Now press Ok and Run.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify any one of the above phase to resolve the above error. In most of the situations, this would have occurred due to running the build from the eclipse environment.

instead of mvn clean package or mvn package you can try only   package  its work fine for me

Comment: Thank you, worked for me in intelliJ IDEA as I wrote "mvn clean install" in command line options instead of only "clean install".

Answer (score 1):

I too got the similar problem and I did like below..
Rt click the project, navigate to Run As --> click 6 Maven Clean and your build will be success..

[image: Maven Clean]

[image: Build Success]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error comes because it's simply the wrong folder. :-(

It shall be the folder which contains the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Create new Maven file with path as classpath and goal as class name

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to Eclipse but just linux shell. I got it because of running

```
mvn .
```

to compile jar package, instead of running

```
mvn
```

which fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Better to check once mvn command you provided. My case I used

**Command:**

```
mvn mvn clean install
```

**Error:**
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal

**Corrected**

```
mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why when i run mvn command with powershell, it doesn't work
but when i change to git bash and run the mvn it works, maybe powershell doesn't support

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.application.instance_id=sergey
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same issue as provided in the technical question ["Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or "](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38930469/8370915) using [POM](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/413bccae37a0ff445a638497c7ee9ba9):

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

I worked with the `Run`/`Debug Configuration` settings as:

[image]

w/ the command as:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

and to fix it, I need to use another one as:

```
clean install -U
```

without `mvn` lifecycle phase and, as result, it should work as:

[image]