# Unable to deploy project to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Eclipse is using Java Development kit 7 with even though it can't get the Java Compiler.

Eclipse error:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you need to use JDK not JRE... you can get jdk from here...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

STEP 1 : Open Command Prompt and Run Below Mentioned Command

**`Echo %PATH%`**

After executing above command check that it is containing entry related to JDK version installed on your
machine (For windows  : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;)
If it does not exist then Add Valid JDK Installation directory path to the PATH Variable(Some Relevant Help can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html))
If you haven't installed JDK, you can download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html))

If you are able to find JDK Related path by executing above command,

Go to STEP 2.

STEP 2 :
Follow the Steps of accepted answer on Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra).