# Maven dependency with JUnit not working with failure to resolve

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

First of all, I'm a real beginner in Maven. I have problems with my first project. Here is my pom file (full):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.fornax</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After saving, maven downloaded the junit-4.12.jar and created a Maven dependencies folders, which is added to build path. After these the testfile have errors, says: **The import org.junit.Test cannot be resolved** and want to add Junit 4 to build path. I'm bit confused what is the problem, but my program not working.

I hope you can help me.

EDIT:::::::
I got some tips: the maven doesn't accept the projectlibs and I should try this settings set in eclipse style. Maybe this helps you to help me?

SOLVED:::::::
Thanks all of your help. I found this page: http://skillshared.blogspot.hu/2012/10/aaa.html and it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: right click on you project > maven > update project > check force update snapshots/ releases > press ok

Comment: if that did not work delete the contents of C:\Users\{your user}\.m2\repository ,,, then repeat above

Comment: I tried it, but this not solved the problem :(

Comment: Please build the artifact (with package or install) and report the results of the build (including the error).

Comment: I have 3 errors:
Test cannot be resolved to a type
The import org.junit.Assert cannot be resolved
The method Fail(String) is undifined for the type AppTest

Comment: Just to be sure: did you place your file under `src/test/java` (instead of `src/main/java`)?

Comment: @RobertScholte yes, i double checked and its there

Comment: I got some tips: the maven dont accept the projectlibs and i should try this settings set in eclipse style. Maybe this helps you to help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "the maven don't accept the projectlibs"?

Comment: Can you post the complete pom file?

Comment: When/where do you see the error? Is it when you run 'mvn test' from a command line or is it in Eclipse/Intellij/<other IDE>?

Comment: After saving the project, i cant run anything cuz the errors

Comment: Have you run `mvn clean install` first?

Comment: Can you post snapshot of your project structure?

Comment: @AnupamaBoorlagadda i cant, i only registered on Friday

Comment: @soorapadman i run the clean install, but i got error **No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?** how can i change that?

Comment: Then you must check this link to resolve :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra

Comment: after i did the changes i got this error when i did clean install: **error reading C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)**

Answer (score 0):

First clean the project and again install the Maven.