# Why can't I run a spring boot application ?

Tags: eclipse, maven

- No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Actually, I'm running JDK both on STS, both on Eclipse.

I  deleted .metadata directory under STS and Eclipse workspace, than restart STS, but the same error comes up..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNINN.jpg)

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have configured in Eclipse. You're trying to run Maven from command line, which needs a proper JDK in the necessary paths. Is the JDK part of the PATH variable?

Comment: @dunni Yes it is.

Comment: But if I try to run it on STS, (Run as Spring Boot App) i got this:             Error: Could not find or load main class org.training.reservations.SpringReservationsApplication

Comment: Add `JAVA_HOME` to system variables with path like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`, and try to run again. And try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279068/5229041

Comment: Now I got this: No plugin found for prefix 'spring boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups