# Putting the JDK properly, maven install still not working

Tags: eclipse, maven

[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

How to resolve this error? 
[image: demo]

Comment: Maybe the wrong path to jdk is configured in your settings.xml (which is specified under prefernces->maven)?

Comment: Separate configuration on console using JAVA_HOME for Maven and the configuration in Eclipse which is unrelated to the running of Maven on the console...The JDK Path is not configured in settings.xml. You have to define the JAVA_HOME variable for the location of JDK.

Comment: @KaranShishoo - NO. This is not duplicate, because the solution given to that issue, doesn't work anymore. I do have the same issue Alexa has. None of the solutions proposed resolve the issue.

Comment: Adding more information to the issue. When Updating maven project, JRE library folds back to J2SE-1.5, instead of staying on jre 1.8.0_241(most current)

Comment: @KyonPerez When I flagged this question as a duplicate (which was over 2 years ago), with the provided information both the questions were identical(they still are just that this one uses an image of the error log while the [linked one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra) shows the text), with one just being older and having an accepted as well as highly upvoted answers. If none of those answers work for you feel free to ask a new question and detail which solutions you have attempted