# No compiler is provided in this environment. maven build failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the following error while using the following command

```
mvn clean install package
```

Error

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have tried the solutions already present online but none of them worked, I have my JDK path selected in the installed JRE's on my eclipse.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Can someone help?

I have already tried the solution given in [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)
but that didn't help. I already have my JDK path selected correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Comment: i already tried that solution, doesn't work

Comment: can you share your pom.xml file? 
Or You verify you have added compiler plugin to it.

Comment: @HassanMudassir i did add the compiler plugin via <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: add the java version for the compiler. 
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

Replace ${java.version} with actual version you use

Comment: Did you even try to googling?

Comment: @MehrajMalik did you even try thinking that i might have tried googling

Comment: If you would have, then you might have solved it.

Comment: @MehrajMalik if you would have, then you would have understood why i had to post this question

Answer (score 1):

Check JAVA_HOME path is set as the environment variable pointing to JDK. Refer maven installation steps for more information.

https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Answer (score 1):

Give the jdk path in /etc/environment

Eg : JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

then

```
source /etc/environment
```

also add in bashrc

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: i have done this, but still same error. java_home is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 correctly, i can see it via echo java_home

Comment: also add in bashrc

    export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
    then run command 
   "source ~/.bashrc"

Comment: did this, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact error.

There are a lot of possible solutions posted for this problem, even more duplicates. However, after checking many of them I did not find the solution. After some tries and investigations among my environment settings I have found out that the issue was caused by having multiple java paths pointing to different versions that were set up by different IDE's. Also, it seems that Maven was trying to use the first version it found in the PATH settings which actually appeared to be a JRE version.

The solution for me was to put the path pointing to Java JDK as the first path in the `PATH` environment settings.

Also, make sure that the new environment settings are in effect before you try to use Maven again.

A very simple way to see if `mvn` actually tries to use the JDK is to execute the following command:

`mvn -version`

It will print out the Java paths along with other info.