# import toml4j in Java fails

Tags: java, maven, toml

I'm trying to import [TOML4J](https://github.com/mwanji/toml4j) into my my maven project. I added this to my dependencies in my POM.xml in the dependencies part:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.moandjiezana.toml</groupId>
    <artifactId>toml4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get an error at

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

saying that it "failed to read artifact descriptor for com.moandjienzana.toml:toml4j:jar:0.7.2"
and a second error that says that said dependency is not found, highlighting the "0.7.2"

EDIT 1: I believe to have fixed *this* issue but if I add

```
import com.moandjiezana.toml.toml4j;
```

to my main file it doesn't recognize the "moandjiezana" part.

EDIT 2: full POM.xml file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.comp.ima.restmesspc</groupId>
  <artifactId>RESTMessPC</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>RESTMessPC</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.maven.apache.org.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.moandjiezana.toml/toml4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.moandjiezana.toml</groupId>
      <artifactId>toml4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

EDIT 3: after doing the clean install I got this Error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.301 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-17T19:08:28+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
7.0:compile (default-compile) on project RESTMessPC: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I do have the JDK installed and IntelliJ recognizes it.

EDIT 4:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Environments/Java/restmesspc/src/main/java/com/comp/ima/restmess
pc/App.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class toml4j
  location: package com.moandjiezana.toml
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.432 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-17T19:30:39+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
7.0:compile (default-compile) on project RESTMessPC: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/Environments/Java/restmesspc/src/main/java/com/comp/ima/restmess
pc/App.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class toml4j
[ERROR]   location: package com.moandjiezana.toml
```

Comment: Actually, I can download the above artifact from maven. Hope you have internet access to download from remote repo.

Comment: I do have an internet connection through a proxy server.
I can even ping the repository through IntelliJ. @notionquest

Comment: IntelliJ has an auto import feature. Go to Settings --> Search for "auto-import". Enable it. Once done, IntelliJ should automatically get the dependencies from repo.

Comment: It was already enabled but it still didn't work.
Sorry if I'm acting stupid but I'm fairly new to using maven.

Comment: Have you installed the Maven on your computer? Are you using windows or Mac? Did you set the MAVEN environment variable correctly? Is this your first Maven project in your computer?

Comment: I use maven as it came (preinstalled to my knowledge) with IntelliJ IDEA. I have a windows PC, I set no variables if it didn't do that automatically and, yes, it is my first maven project.

Comment: Also it can't be a problem with the Proxy Server as I'm currently trying it in my home network.

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't install the Maven software. It just has plugins to work with Maven and other build softwares (like SBT). You may need to install the maven. Please follow this link https://maven.apache.org/install.html to install Maven (and set the env variables correctly). Then, try it. It should work.

Comment: edit: I installed maven seperately now and added it to the PATH variable.

mvn -v responds

Comment: Good. Now go to IntelliJ, open POM file, right click and select "Maven --> Reimport". It should download the artifact.

Comment: It now says again that it "failed to read the artifact descriptor for com.moandjiezana.toml:toml4j:jar:0.7.2"

Comment: Can you please add your full POM file in the OP? Also, please try this command "mvn clean install" on the project directory?

Comment: I added it and got the Error as stated in OP.

I feel like this is a simple error but I just can't find it...

Comment: Looks like you have set the JAVA_HOME incorrectly. It would be something like this JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31. Use set JAVA_HOME=<path to JDK folder>. Then, try mvn clean install. Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra

Comment: Thank you! It actually wasn't even set in the first place. Starting to compile works now. I get a new error message though (see OP)

Comment: I think the original issue is resolved now. It would be great if you can accept this answer and open a new issue for the new problem (for better clarity).

Comment: It isn't solved yet. I still get the same error (failed to read artifact descriptor) at the project tag.

Comment: Alright. After anothe rfew hours of trying out every combination of setting I finally got it to work. Thanks for the help @notionquest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some more research I found that IntelliJ basically just didn't want to write into an already failed import folder.

So deleting the folder of the dependency you want to import in `C:\user\[user]\.m2\repository` and doing a reimport should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:-

1. Install MAVEN using the instructions in the [link](https://maven.apache.org/install.html). You should have JAVA 7or installed as well
2. Set the environment variables (i.e. JAVA HOME and Maven path should be set)
3. Verify the successful installation using the maven command `mvn -v`
4. If the Maven version is displayed successfully, then try the auto import feature in IntelliJ. It should download the artifact from remote repository
5. Go to IntelliJ
6. Open POM xml file --> Right click --> Maven --> Reimport

**Edit:-**

1. Please ensure that JDK 7 or 8 is installed and JAVA_HOME is set correctly
2. Use `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` to set the Java home correctly