# Maven build in error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am getting the following error while trying to do maven build.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project

Maven version is 3.5.3 . maven compiler plugin version is 3.7.0. Is there any issue because of it?

I installed jdk1.8. So, that is the default version using in eclipse.
plugin specified in pom.xml like as follows (which was auto generated).

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Mine is a spring mvc project. I think , my codes and code configurations are correct. Something wrong with maven . I deleted the .me/repository . But no change were made. IDE using is Eclipse Oxygen.

Complete log included

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringEg1.0 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SpringMVC ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Sreevidya Aravind\eclipse-workspace\SpringExample\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SpringMVC ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sreevidya Aravind\eclipse-workspace\SpringExample\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ SpringMVC ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Sreevidya Aravind\eclipse-workspace\SpringExample\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.225 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-01T18:07:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project SpringMVC: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: From the information in the question, it's possible that the problem is in the code. Can you perhaps add the complete error?

Comment: normally maven provides some more information about what exactly goes wrong. for (even) more detailed information: repeat the command with flag -X

Comment: Different version of maven and plugins should not be an issue. You should get a more detailed error message after what you have posted.

Comment: I included the complete log.

Comment: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: its answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Comment: Verified. Running on JDK. But the build failed with it.

Comment: adding this resolved the issue. <configuration>
     <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
     <executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>

Comment: What does `javac -version` say?  What does `mvn -V` say?

Answer (score 0):

Please try editing the jre from the below path,so that it points to the jdk-

Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs