# Spring STS - Maven build error - No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? Spring

Tags: spring, maven

[Installed JRE pointing to JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF0Ma.png) &   [Libraries pointing to jre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApbF1.png)[Please note- there solutions out there Eclipse, but I'm using Sprint STS]
Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.3.RELEASE 
Apache Maven 3.2.5
Java- 10.0.1
OS - Windows 10
Tomcat 8.5

I have already verified Installed JRE has a JDK entry. Have verified JAVA_HOME and Path environment variables.

Maven Clean & Validate works. Maven Compile does not work. 
Gives me error - "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? "

Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Answer (score 3):

Your workspace needs to be configured with a JDK.

Goto `Preferences->Java->Installed JREs` and `Add` your JRE there.  Point at a JRE (with a JDK).

[image]

Then right-click on your project and select `Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add Library` to make sure that JRE is associated with your project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, I would like to share my screen shots, but i don't know how. how can I share my screen shots showing all the settings I currently have ?

Comment: Perhaps edit your original question.  That will allow you to attach screenshots from your computer

Comment: Paul i have attached 2 screen shots showing installed JRE and libraries. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error while using spring tool suite 4 IDE.

To resolve these issues, follow these steps:

- Right click on project
- Select Build path option
- Click on configure Build path
- Go to libraries tab
- Click on Add Library option
- Select JRE System Library
- Select Alternate JRE option
- Click on installed JRE's button
- Click on ADD
- Select Standard VM
- Click on directory
- Select the path to JDK
- Click Apply & Close.

That's it, issue was resolved and maven build was successful.

I hope this works for eclipse too. It worked for me.