# failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have tools.jar in JDK but in pom.xml `java.home` is getting evaluated wrongly pls see the pic for that. How to point it at `c:/user/username/java/openjdk`?

[image: Error Info]

In eclipse windows -preferences-java-installed JRE I have provided the JDK path

In environment variables also I have provided the right path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring STS - Maven build error - No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662239/spring-sts-maven-build-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-pe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the dependence are getting downloaded.
Make sure cloning of project is done completely.
This error comes when something is missing in the project either be it dependency,any source file even a import can led to this error