# No compiler is provided

Tags: java, maven, aem

I'm trying to run an AEM project. I successfully added it from cmd and now I'm trying to run it from InteliJ but I'm getting error.

Im trying with `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage` because I have running instance and want to build and package the whole project and deploy AEM with it.

Error is: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project aem-guides-wknd-full.core: Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`

### `javac 1.8.0_202`

`java version "1.8.0_321"`

In env variables I set for `User variables` `path > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`

And in `System Variables` in `Path` I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`

Comment: You have to set `JAVA_HOME` as environment variable pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202` nothing else... Also of course the installation of Maven in your PATH...apart from that check the version of JDK you are using...

Comment: Have you defined a JAVA_HOME env variable set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202` ?

Comment: You have to set the JAVA_HOME in env variables . Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19655276/8671041