# Mirror API in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I downloaded the glass-java-starter from github and followed all of the instructions on the glass developers site.  I got it imported into Eclipse as a Maven existing project as instructed and I changed the oAuth file ID and Secret as specified.  When I try to start the project or debug the project I am getting the following exception:  Source not found for http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException.  The instructions give a command line command for running the project, $ mvn jetty, but nothing for Eclipse.  How do I debug this project with Eclipse?

Comment: It has very little to do with google mirror api and nothing in common with google-glass in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use one of the maven plugins available for Eclipse to initiate the run:jetty goal.

There are a few available. One of them is [Eclipse m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

1. [Install the plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/)
2. Create a new run configuration of type Maven Build
3. Specify a goal of `jetty:run`

Comment: OK,I put run:jetty in the maven build configuration and now I am getting this error:  COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error

Comment: This sounds like a maven + java issue. There are lots of possible causes. This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099072/eclipse-maven-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment

Answer (score 1):

Other solution would be:

set jetty debug port:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=y'
```

then run jetty through maven command line

```
mvn jetty:jetty
```

After that use Eclipse remote debugger on port 4000.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please see my comment under Jenny Murphy's answer and maybe help me out on that?  Also, can you please give me an up.   Someone gave me a negative and I have no idea why.

Comment: javac is a program shipped with JDK (along with many other artefacts which differ JDK from JRE). If you try to run "javac -version" in the same terminal window it will tell you the compiller version if it is available or not. if not - you will need to setup JDK. The link Jenny mentioned has sufficient answer on cases like yours.

Answer (score 1):

The war file, product that mvn produce in this sample app is compatible with tomcat or any other standalone server, so just build a war to "webapp" directory of standalone tomcat or jetty or "deploy" directory of standalone JBoss. 
Eclipse has plenty of plugins to run those in debug mode.