# Eclipse: Pattern can't be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried looking for a solution to this error but still can't use the class `java.util.regex.Pattern`, So I tried to make the import manually but I can only see three classes `Matcher`, `MatchResult` and `PatternSyntaxException`.

When looking in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\src.zip` I can see the `Pattern.java` file, and I can see also the class Pattern.class when opening the JAR `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar`.

Could someone help why Eclipse can't see this `Pattern` class?

This is the error as you can see it in Eclipse:
[image]

Comment: See if it help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21099229/460557

Comment: thanks for your reply, i see that i dont have anything in the "Compatible JREs" side, even when i click on JavaSE-1.6... how can i resolve that?

Comment: Click on add button, choose default jvm, then point it to your JDK enviroment, it normally are on c:\program files\java\jdk_xxx if you are on widnows

Comment: I am not talking about Installed JREs, i have jdk there ... but i am talking about "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments", when i Select JavaSE-1.6, i can't see anything on the right like what link you sent to me described

Comment: The link I provided is about the JREs not the Execution Enviroment. These problems is normally related to the IDE with an embeded JRE. Thats why I pointed you to that link. I suggest you then to download another version of eclipse and import your project.

Comment: Ok and thx for your help Jorge, but i want also to tell you that i have many other classes complied and work fine, i just had that issue only when trying to use that Pattern class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the JDK I was using, probably a corrupted file or installation issues, I tried another JDK version (1.6) and its working fine now.