# When Jenkins Building a maven project gave Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter Jenkins

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter Jenkins.
```

The following error I got from building a maven project from jenkins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added this to my pom xml plugins. Which Resolved all my problems.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you also explain why this resolved the problem?

Comment: Explanation of issue and fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016532/3368558