# How to fail build in case of a SurefireBooterForkException?

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I sometimes have SurefireBooterForkException but the jenkins build is not failed or even test failures are stated (i.e. build is green) and one has to recognize oneself that tests are simply missing in the test result, i.e. there is no information about tests that could not be run.

I found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1426 where this is discussed for the configuration parameter `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore`, but I don't use this parameter.

Which parameters could also have impact? How could I force a SurefireBooterForkException to verify if that happens reproducible or if other side effects need to be relevant, too?

I don't know if that is important, but I have seen this in integration tests with a fully deployed application, i.e. Selenium tests running in a real scenario (not only Unit tests).

Maven Output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.21.0:verify (verify) on project SeleniumTests: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\SeleniumTests\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] javax/inject/Provider
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.21.0:verify (verify) on project SeleniumTests: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\SeleniumTests\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
javax/inject/Provider
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\SeleniumTests\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
javax/inject/Provider
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException(SurefireHelper.java:235)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.failsafe.VerifyMojo.execute(VerifyMojo.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] Build failures were ignored.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the OpenJdk backport to Ubuntu was an issue. I could not predict scenarios in which this bug becomes a problem, but I noticed the bug on every latest Ubuntu-based distributions; older versions were not affected.

To tackle this, I appended the following POM snippet to the Surefire plugin configurations:

```
<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
```

Next, I configured the JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable for Maven processes:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true
```

NOTE: It is important that the variable is passed to the entire call to Maven and the Surefire plugin.

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptPos=${0%/*}

# This is a workaround script for a bug in the OpenJDK backport on Ubuntu.
# Bug causes problems in the Surefire plugin.
# https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1588
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010200/maven-surefire-could-not-find-forkedbooter-class

_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true mvn $@
```

In Bamboo, it is sufficient to set the environment variable within a plan's configuration.

Comment: It's still version 8. I found the core reason is a dependency on another module I added. It is a WAR module and thus I have used the maven configuration `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` in the maven-war-plugin and add the dependency with `<classifier>classes</classifier>`. But why is that an issue for surefire? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: After what i have read it will have to do with the spawn of new processes ... found that, but their advice was not clear for me https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html

Comment: I played with the configuration, but I think there is a CDI issue in the dependent module here that is not affected by these settings. The output states:
Please refer to C:\SeleniumTests\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
**javax/inject/Provider**
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)

Comment: No I removed all CDI stuff and the `beans.xml`, but the SurefireBooterForkException is still occurring. Also if I delete everything in this module it is working again. Can't strip it down to a core reason effectively.