# SpringBoot and GitLab CI give maven surefire error

Tags: maven, spring-boot, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to build my Spring Boot project automatically with Gitlab CI, but it gives me the following error message. I've already tried a few solutions that I found here, but nothing worked for me. When I run `mvn package -B` on my local machine, it runs without any error.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.432 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-09T17:38:27Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project ft-backend: There are test failures.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Please refer to /builds/festivaltinder/backend/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    [ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /builds/festivaltinder/backend && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /builds/festivaltinder/backend/target/surefire/surefirebooter482613920128694439.jar /builds/festivaltinder/backend/target/surefire 2018-11-09T17-14-53_842-jvmRun1 surefire5530268903330789280tmp surefire_01102852336946345213tmp
    [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
    [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
    [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /builds/festivaltinder/backend && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /builds/festivaltinder/backend/target/surefire/surefirebooter482613920128694439.jar /builds/festivaltinder/backend/target/surefire 2018-11-09T17-14-53_842-jvmRun1 surefire5530268903330789280tmp surefire_01102852336946345213tmp
    [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
    [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    ERROR: Job failed: exit code
```

Here is the pom.xml code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.tf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ft-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

At least the maven build code in my gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
maven-build:
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    stage: build
    script: "mvn package -B"
    artifacts:
        paths:  
            - target/*.jar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010200/maven-surefire-could-not-find-forkedbooter-class/53016532#53016532) [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1588).

Add this to your pom:

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: After one year... after a year the bug was discovered we still have to use a "pork-around" and use a not released version of maven-surefire-plugin.... bha...

PS thank you @Kieveli, you saved my day.

Comment: Revisit this again later - having strict versions for plugins isn't the best option. I'm not sure what the correct way to fix this will become next month, or later this year.