# Maven surefire illegal argument exception

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

When running Junit 5 tests on a Java jar and loading a dependency there's
warning

```
Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file O:\VSTS\_work\2\s\target\surefire-reports\2019-11-04T13-14-53_351-jvmRun1.dumpstream
```

When I go look at the dumpstream it's full of comments like:

```
Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream '13:14:57.199 6960-Log            dbug    system      Thread::GoThread                    Thread 6960-Log started.'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream stdin corrupted. Expected comma after third character in command '13:14:57.199   6960-Log            dbug    system      Thread::GoThread                    Thread 6960-Log started.'.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient$OperationalData.<init>(ForkClient.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.processLine(ForkClient.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consumeLine(ForkClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's gone wrong with the surefire booterclient?

Per [Maven surefire could not find ForkedBooter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010200/maven-surefire-could-not-find-forkedbooter-class) to set

```
<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
```

resolved the dependency loading problem but not the corrupted stream.

Answer (score 0):

The error resolved by setting forkCount to 0

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
          <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
          <concordion.output.dir>target/concordion</concordion.output.dir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```