# Debugging "org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process null" error

Tags: maven, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm having an issue diagnosing a problem with an automated test framework. I wasn't the one who set it up, so there are some knowledge gaps in my understanding but any help would be appreciated. I've attached some information below to help troubleshoot the problem.

**Additional comments that may be useful:**

1. This is being run on a Linux machine
2. This works on my local Windows eclipse IDE, but not the Linux machine
3. Removing the `<suiteXmlFiles>` within the `pom.xml` file removes the error, it just passes because there's 0 tests, but we never run into the error

**Here is a list of fixes that I tried:**

1. Changing the owner of the files to the user running `mvn test`
2. Changing the version of `maven-surefire-plugin` to a variety of different versions
3. Changing the read/write/execute permissions of `pom.xml` and the `Testng.xml` file
4. Added forkCount 0 per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010200/maven-surefire-could-not-find-forkedbooter-class)

**Error when running `mvn test`**

```
Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Trax_Automation-ProdValidation-Test-Backup/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
There was an error in the forked process
null
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
null
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException (SurefireHelper.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1041)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
null
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork (ForkStarter.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>traxKOUR</groupId>
        <artifactId>traxKOUR</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>traxV1</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <!-- Plug-ins required for executing Tests -->
        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.2</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.7</source>
                                        <target>1.7</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.22.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                                                <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                                                <suiteXmlFile>Testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                                        <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                </plugins>

        </build>
        <!-- Dependencies required for Project -->

        <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
                        <version>v1-rev105-1.25.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.testautomationguru.pdfutil/pdf-util -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.testautomationguru.pdfutil</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pdf-util</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Checking pdf file and whether is corrupted or not -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.j256.simplemagic</groupId>
                        <artifactId>simplemagic</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                        <version>3.14.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.2</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                        <version>7.1.0</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                        <version>3.17</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.16</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.17</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.5</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.17</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple FOR TEST RAIL -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json FOR TEST RAIL -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                        <version>20200518</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TraxV1">
        <listeners>
                <listener class-name="com.trax.utilities.Reporting" />
        </listeners>
        <test name="trax Test">
                <parameter name="browser" value="chromeLinux" />
                <!-- <groups> <run> <include name="smoke" /> <exclude name= "krishna" />
                        </run> </groups> -->
                <classes>
                    <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readPublicPrivateFilters" />
                    <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readTraxitInternalEventNotes" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readUsersProjectsProposals" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readActiveCustomersActiveSuppliers" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readAttachmentsAPInvoices" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readAttachmentsChkLogsBidsSubmittalsBills" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readBlueBeamForJobProject" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readCollectionsScoreboard" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readCompanyRepCommissionViewer" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readInternalProjectRevenueTable" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readJobSearchPurchaseAgencyOrders" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readMfrNonInventoriedProducts" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readMfrQuotaReport" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readReleaseNotesCompanyLinks" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readSOTUReports" />
                        <class name="com.trax.testCases.TC_readSubmittalsTraxits" />
                </classes>
        </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You are using pretty old plugins versions (both surefire and compiler). It would be good to check if the same error happens if you update them.