# Java 1.8.65 javac is missing

Tags: java, windows, installation

I downloaded the newst 1.8.65 JDK a few days ago an the javac file is missing

in case someone believes I accidently downloaded the JRE, here are 2 screenshots

[image: oracle]

when I browse to the directory I installed the JDK in

```
C:\Enwicklung\JDK\1.8.65\bin
```

the javac.exe file isn't there where it should be, as you can see in this second screenshot

[image: folder]

can anyone confirm this? tried to install the JDK a second time without any change.

EDIT: of course I searched the whole drive for a javac.exe, no match was found

Comment: Download the Server jre, it contains a jdk. Don't forget that the jdk contains both the jdk _and_ a jre, perhaps you mixed directories

Comment: I will give the server jre a try, searched the whole disk for a javac.exe none was installed and I'm relatively sure I didn't mix any folders cause I installed Win 10 on an empty drive

Comment: I like how you misspelled `Entwicklung`

Comment: now that you mention it :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve the "problem" myself. after rechecking every letter of the installation process.

During installation, the installer asks you where you want to install the JDK

[image]

I chose the folder `C:\Enwicklung\JDK\1.8.65\`

A progress bar is displayed and installation continues

Then you are asked

[image]

for non-German native speakers

**Zielordner** = target folder
**Ändern** = change

In this view, the installation process is asking in which folder I want to install Java

I chose the folder `C:\Entwicklung\JDK\1.8.65\` again this leads to the following conflict

in `C:\Entwicklung\JDK\1.8.65\` there was a `bin\` folder of the JDK installation

The JRE aka its alias Java, which a mindful reader should have noticed, but I obviously missed twice, was installed in the same location overwriting the `bin\` folder of the JDK with the `bin\` folder of the JRE, deleting all files.

[image]

An unneeded mistake on my side. Unfortunately, the German installation process doesn't state anywhere that the JRE is being installed except in the folder name of the **Zielorder** view and that it's installed in the base folder structure.

In my defense, the installation process does not state explicitly that the JRE is being installed next and the installation, at least in this German version, doesn't warn that folders and files are going to be overwritten, which is an undesirable effect from my point of view.

NOTE: I left the predefined folder name as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65` because otherwise after changing it to `C:\Entwicklung\JDK\1.8.65\` there would have been no indication for you to know that the JRE is being installed

Comment: Short version: he installed the Java and it didn't come with `javac.exe`.