# Error on Importing existing Maven project to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported a Maven project in to my Eclipse after that I ran maven clean. I am facing an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/home/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclips>e.m2e.launching/launches/m2conf9054790604023893654.tmp (No such file or >directory).at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
>     at  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:390)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356).

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21099229/460557

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the .m2 folder in your home directory. This folder contains the repository of all the maven dependencies (jars) that we will be using in our code.
In case the .m2 folder was not created by default when you installed eclipse, or if the version of eclipse you have does not support maven, install a version that has the maven plugin by default.
Another option you can try is to create the .m2/repository folder in your home directory manually.