# Eclipse can not find the class build by maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am using `Eclipse Mars` for a maven project. The project was imported as a maven project. Maven can build, but when I want to run a `JUnit` test with `Eclipse` I have the message :

> Class not found

result when I try to launch the test with `Eclipse`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class not found nameOfTheClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

If I launch the test with `Maven`, with external tools, part of the answer is :

```
maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ NameOfModule --- [INFO]
```

Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

So `Maven` can compile and build...

Comment: please put exact stack trace you got as error

Comment: Please post a trace or the messages that appeared.

Comment: try Alt-F5 which will rebuild the maven config, if that does not work try building from command line mvn clean install.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587788/errors-while-importing-maven-project-into-eclipse/41587897#41587897

Comment: I have made a clean compile install with maven.

Comment: I have edited the first message

Comment: @EssexBoy I tried but it did not work.

Comment: Classes are build but eclipse can not find them.

Comment: I would blow the whole project away, make sure you delete the hidden files and directories like .project, and re-import as a maven project.

Comment: @EssexBoy already tried

Comment: To conclude : I reinstall once more the project, i work on the module's part and it work, i don't use the parent's folder.