# No compiler is provided in this environment. - Eclipse - Maven - java-8-openjdk - Xubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I use Eclipse, Maven and java8-openjdk.

1. I am using JDK not JRE:

   [image: Build path screenshot.]

   [image: Installed JREs -> Execution environment screenshot]

   Java is located at `**/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/**`.
2. The class with `main` method compiles and runs without a problem.
3. I was able to build before without any problems.
4. The runtime version of Eclipse:

   ```
   java.runtime.version=1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14
   ```
5. In `pom.xml`, I have Maven compiler plugin, with version `3.5.1`, source and target values `1.8`.

What am I missing here ? I have configured correct path. I have JDK. I did builds before and yet Maven is failing now.

Please let me know how to start about finding the root cause and also let me know if any more information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: what does `echo $JAVA_HOME` print ?

Comment: *I was able to build before without any problems.* What changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099072/eclipse-maven-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment

Comment: @niceman /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

Comment: @StephenC I already have all the settings that are described in that answer.  Also I have referred all the questions related to this issue in SO.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Nothing. Or nothing I know of. Since the last time I ran a build I was working on a particular file, changing and executing that alone. My doubt is whether I am doing anything fundamentally wrong or missed something.

Comment: What about ```JAVE_HOME```, is it set ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein see comments :3

Comment: if you're using eclipse to build, try to build from the command line using `mvn package` (execute the command where pom.xml exists)

Comment: @niceman In command line also the same error.

Comment: can you show us the full output from that command ?

Comment: What does ```javac -version``` yields ? do you see ```javac``` under ```$JAVA_HOME/bin``` ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein javac 1.8.0_91

Comment: Can you share your ```pom``` file ?

Comment: The pom xml [https://gist.github.com/Aravamudhan/40aeaee30c61f615384cfa1dd6b04884]

Comment: @niceman The output of package command [https://gist.github.com/Aravamudhan/511deba3f98130d38e90a836e0da08cd]

Comment: links are broken :(

Comment: Both the links are available. Please check this https://gist.github.com/Aravamudhan

Comment: @AmudhanBala Do you see ```tools.jar``` under ```$JAVA_HOME/lib``` ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein No it is not available.

Comment: @AmudhanBala so this seems to be your problem, I've added an explanation below.

Comment: I re installed java-8-openjdk-amd64. The build has succeeded. I could have reinstalled long before spending a lot of time on it, but would never have known the cause to be one particular jar. Now this package contains all the necessary jars. Thanks a lot every one for your helping hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.x is using `tools.jar` for compilation rather then `javac`, please make sure this jar is present under `$JAVA_HOME/lib` and eclipse has permissions to access it.

You should also verify that `tools.jar` exists under Windows->Preferences->Installed JREs, and if it is not, add it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help. java-8-openjdk-amd64, which I installed does not have tools.jar and dt.jar by default. I will add them and check.

Comment: My jdk had the tools.jar installed but they were not added in the "Installed JRE" on eclipse. Its all good after adding those.