# Maven compilation Error creating artifacts and copying them into the local repository

Tags: java, maven

I have this compilation error un maven

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
```

But It's not possible because I have the jdk in my path: `;..;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin`

and:

```
C:\Development\Workspaces\EclipseWS\devices-project>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and here mvn -v :

```
C:\Users\joanet>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:
28+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Package Compilation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220392/maven-package-compilation-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `mvn -v` you will see what Maven thinks it is using

e.g.

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-15T03:59:23+10:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Is your problem one of these StackOverflow errors?

[Eclipse/Maven error: "No compiler is provided in this environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099072/eclipse-maven-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment)

[No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

[Maven error :Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313902/maven-error-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-rather-than-a-jdk)

[Maven Package Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220392/maven-package-compilation-error)

Or any of the other google answers.

Comment: true, its this: Java home: C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre, but I don't know from where it comes from, becasue I have my JAVA_HOME set to C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\

Comment: Can you update your question with the results of mvn -v?