# Maven Error: No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, maven

When I run my maven project, this error apear!
althought, the sdk is added and everything is ok!!

I don't know what's the problem here!? 
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried running any maven command from the command line?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/21279068/5588347

Comment: I have already tried this, and always with the same error!

Comment: hmm can you show me the complete error message?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project abay-ejb: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: Hopefully the JRE install had managed to overwrite JDK's /bin folder. Try reinstalling the JDK and make sure you're not installing the JRE over it when you're prompted to install the JRE afterwards

Comment: Also refer this site: http://roufid.com/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment/ as well as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220392/maven-package-compilation-error

Comment: if you are on ubuntu than try doing this: `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-lib`

Comment: I reinstalled the JDK and it worked :D I'm not sure about what was the error exactly, I think a problem in the path of the JDK..thank you for your help

Comment: cool :) glad that I could help.